# ASP. NET Core Call Web API from Razor View

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, api, razor

I build a Razor View for my web app layout. In my Layout I want to get a user's photo in my layout. But, the problem is how to get the user's photo from the web api and return it to Razor View

Here's my API code:

```
[HttpGet("employee-photo/{employeeId}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetEmployeePhoto(string employeeId)
{
    var employeeIdClaim = this.UtilityService.GetEmployeeIdClaim(User);
    if (employeeId != employeeIdClaim)
    {
        return null;
    }
    var employeePhoto = await this.FileStorage.GetEmployeePhoto(employeeId);
    var name = employeeId + ".jpg";

    return File(employeePhoto, "image/jpg", name);
}
```

and here's my Razor View

```
<a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle text-white" href="#" id="userDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
   <img src="@Url.Action("/api/v1/blob/employee-photo/18060001")" /><span class="hidden-xs">@User.Claims.Where(Q => Q.Type == "FullName").Select(Q => Q.Value).FirstOrDefault()</span>
   <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
</a>
```

`api/v1/blob` is my API path, I just not write it all of the other code here

Can i get photo(image) from my API to my Razor View? How? Thanks

Comment: Try put a breakpoint inside the controller, is it reaches that breakpoint? If the debugger never reaches that breakpoint, probably you're not using `Url.Action` properly.

Comment: no, i tried that, it's not hit the api
yeah, maybe i'm not using Url.Action Properly, or maybe there is another way to call api from view?

Comment: Probably you should use the path directly without `Url.Action`, e.g. `<img src="/api/v1/blob/employee-photo/18060001" />`. Since your URL path uses attribute routing, the `@Url.Action()` seems not applicable because it requires proper controller and action name.

Comment: it's not working

Comment: Is the controller breakpoint now reached? There are still other things that wrongly set besides the API URL itself, I assumed the image still not displayed at this time.

Comment: And what thing currently doesn't work? Is the controller code throwing exception? Also check the file returned from controller, maybe the browser asked for download instead of displaying it?

Answer (score 2):

If you're looking for [`@Url.Action()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.urlhelperextensions.action?view=aspnetcore-2.1#Microsoft_AspNetCore_Mvc_UrlHelperExtensions_Action_Microsoft_AspNetCore_Mvc_IUrlHelper_System_String_) extension method overloads, you will see one overload which takes string parameter like this:

```
public static string Action(this Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.IUrlHelper helper, string action)
```

The `action` refers to actual action method name (i.e. `GetEmployeePhoto`), not the API URL which has been set in `HttpGetAttribute`. Hence, this API URL call is wrong and never reach the API controller action:

```
<img src="@Url.Action("/api/v1/blob/employee-photo/18060001")" />
```

You should use full URL string without `@Url.Action()` helper to make it work:

```
<img src="/api/v1/blob/employee-photo/18060001" />
```

Answer (score 1):

As explained before answer, Url.Action is not right way to get photo from api in that case.

There is nothing abnormal in your GetEmployeePhoto method in my opinion. Just use direct url like:

```
<img src="/api/v1/blob/employee-photo/18060001" />
```

Still you're not getting image, just try followings:

- Set a breakpoint to your method.
- Request directly your api endpoint from browser.
- If debugger reaches to breakpoint, check the behavior of your method 
  (your method should return photo as download).
- If your method is not act like expected or returns error, please share it here.
- If debugger not reaches to breakpoint just check your api routes.